# SQL Server 2005 migration to SQL Server 2014 express

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-express

Recently, we tried the SQL 2005 direct migration to SQL 2014. So far, we have faced quite a few problems in this direct migration. So, we are planning to try the side by side migration. I.e install new instance of SQL2014 and then attach the databases from 2005.

We feel that this would solve some of the issues we faced in the direct migration.

Will there be any difference in the free space requirement between the direct and side by side migration? Any idea on how much space would be required for these 2 things?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need space for it. 
How much? - At least the same size you have now.

However, if you do it only as "one database at the time" it will need as much space as your biggest database.

Also, if you have Enterprise edition and you have a lot of text data you can use "page compression" of your largest tables and save a lot of space.